# Insert two values with same name to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web

I Have form where I want insert let's say:

1. Who paid ? (user_id) in user database

   2. when (date) incomes database
   3. how much (sum) incomes database
   4. Who entering the data (user_id) in user database

and inserting script:

```
if(empty($_POST['user_id'])){
    $data_missing[] = 'User';

} else{
   $summa = trim($_POST['user_id']);   }
.......

$sql = "INSERT INTO incomes (user_id, date, sum, user_id)
VALUES ('$user_id','$date','$sum','$user_id')";
```

......

How I can solve to insert two times "user_id", and they may be different or same!

Comment: You can't have two fields with same name in a single table. What is your database structure?

Comment: Let's say I don't have table yet, but how can I solve this problem. 
I need to do table where I must insert payer ( user) when, how much, and who are entering the information ( it's can be same user, or soma another user)

Comment: Just give different names to your fields. You are not required to call your field `user_id` if it references a user ID. (Foreign keys are in charge of that.)

Comment: give them names that make sense like `user_who_paid` and `user_who_entered_data`....

Comment: Deem,  of course. I have been sitting too long in the tables

Comment: Also, try to avoid naming your fields `date` or `sum`. These are reserved keywords, one day or another you'll have a problem with it.

Comment: But for there raises a new question, when I need to display the names

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to consider your schema first, your `INSERT` second.

If you need two different references to the same table, consider:

```
paying_user_id INT,
added_user_id INT
```

If you use a convention where the `user_id` part is prefixed with some descriptor in a consistent manner this is pretty easy to follow.